# why python3 inspect.isawaitable return 256?

Tags: python-3.5

[image: python]

as the picture shows. What is the meaning of 256 here and why not return True? Thanks for any help
!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should treat it as a "truthy" value. It's actually a CPython's implementation detail which you should probably not concern yourself about. Just do:

```
if inspect.isawaitable(coro):
```

In case you wonder, here's the implementation of said function from inspect.py:

```
def isawaitable(object):
"""Return true is object can be passed to an ``await`` expression."""
return (isinstance(object, types.CoroutineType) or
        isinstance(object, types.GeneratorType) and
            object.gi_code.co_flags & CO_ITERABLE_COROUTINE or
        isinstance(object, collections.abc.Awaitable))
```

The piece responsible for your return value is

```
object.gi_code.co_flags & CO_ITERABLE_COROUTINE
```

Which actually evaluates to 256(2^8).